# Accidentally clicking DLC when low level

Tags: borderlands-2

In the DLC for Borderlands 2, I accidentally clicked it when I was a low level and when I became level 33, I wanted to play it but it was still low level. Is there a way to fix that? I tried finishing the quest to see if the game will adjust to my level but it did not.

Comment: The game won't "adjust" to your level. You just have to keep going until you are powerful and/or high enough level.

Comment: Which dlc is it?

Answer (score 7):

I know it's pretty late for this answer, but I might as well explain how to do this for the people who might stumble upon this question in the future.

Found this after some fiddling around, because I encountered this problem just now (my friend accidentally fast traveled to a DLC area weeks ago) and it is quite annoying now that the enemies there didn't scale when they should have. Shame since it's one of the best areas to grind XP and loot for too (Headhunter 2: Wattle Gobbler).

---

### How to Re-Scale Enemies & Obtainable Loot to Your Current Level?

Keeping in mind that this is not possible within the game itself, you will need to use an external save editor called **[Gibbed's Borderlands 2 Save Editor](https://github.com/gibbed/Gibbed.Borderlands2/releases/download/1.0.46/bl2_saveedit_1.0.46.zip)** (GBSE henceforth).

1. You'll obviously need GBSE (linked above). Don't worry, the link is not malicious, you can get it from their [GitHub project](https://github.com/gibbed/Gibbed.Borderlands2) page yourself, if you don't trust me.
2. If you're playing BL2 on a different platform/console, you'll need to extract the save yourself. You can search it up, I won't cover doing that here because that's going to make this answer much much lengthier.
3. Open your BL2 save file. To make finding the file you want to edit easier, open the game, load that file then save and quit. Sort the files listed in GBSE's browser descendingly according to their modified date.
4. For the purpose of this answer, let's call that file `Save0001.sav`.
5. With the file opened, click on the `Raw` tab in the columns/buttons above. It's the second button from the right.
6. Under that tab, scroll down until you find a row called `RegionGameStages`, click on the `(Collection)` text to the right of it.
7. Now, another window should open. You'll see a bunch of `RegionGameStageData` entries to the left, and their data to the right. You'll have to check each and every one of the entries to the left and look at the `Region` value to the right and see if your DLC's (the one you want to reset) codename is in there. Refer to the text at the bottom of this answer to know your DLC codenames. In my case, it's Headhunter 2, which is `Allium`. I saw one entry with the `Region` value `GD_Allium_GameStages.Regions.Allium_Gamestage_Thanksgiving`, you can see that the codename `Allium` is in the value.
8. Now, once you find an entry corresponding to step #7, you have two choices, (1) either you manually change the `GameStage` value (to the right) to the current level you are at (you can set it higher, [normal scaling rules posted by Powerlord](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/328369/accidentally-clicking-dlc-when-low-level/329794#329794) will still apply, so there's a limit to it) OR (2) you can just completely delete the entry by pressing the X symbol in the middle of the window.
9. Do this for all entries with the DLC's codename in the `Region` field.
10. All done! Now go fast travel in the game to the DLC area and all enemies and new loot should be scaled to your level.

NOTE: This won't reset the missions/quests you've already finished for the DLC. I'll brefly explain it below, but you'll have to do most of the work yourself.

---

### How to Reset Missions/Quests for a Certain DLC?

This one isn't as difficult as you might think. There's no need for step-by-step instructions like before. I'll just briefly explain it.

On the same `Raw` tab in GBSE, look until you find an entry called `MissionPlaythroughs`, clicking on `(Collection)` will show you a window with three entries to the left, these entries correspond to:

- The first `MissionPlaythroughData` is **Normal Mode**.
- The second `MissionPlaythroughData` is **True Vault Hunter Mode**.
- The third `MissionPlaythroughData` is **Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode**.

Select the playthrough you wish to change from the left now look at the entries to the right. You should see an entry called `MissionData`, open that up, another window should open.

So, just like above when you were re-scaling the DLC area, look for entries to the left with your DLC's codename. One such example for my selected `Allium` DLC is:

- `GD_Allium_TG_Plot_Mission01.M_Allium_ThanksgivingMission01`

Simply delete the entry, and the game will automatically let you do that mission again once you load into the area. Do keep in mind that you can further edit these entries per mission objective, etc., but I won't cover that here as that's pretty complicated and needs a lot of trial and error.

So now, obviously, if you want to reset all missions for a specific DLC, then look for entries with that DLC's codename, and delete every entry that has it.

---

### What Are the DLC Codenames?

Refer to the following table to find out your specific DLC's codename and to know which ones to delete:

| DLC Name | DLC Codename |
| --- | --- |
| Borderlands 2 | Willow2 |
| Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty | Orchid |
| Commander Lilith & the Fight for Sanctuary | Anemone |
| Headhunter 1: Bloody Harvest | Flax |
| Headhunter 2: Wattle Gobbler | Allium |
| Headhunter 3: Mercenary Day | Allium |
| Headhunter 4: Wedding Day Massacre | Nasturtium |
| Headhunter 5: Son of Crawmerax | Nasturtium |
| Mechromancer Pack | Tulip |
| Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage | Iris |
| Psycho Pack | Lilac |
| Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt | Sage |
| Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep | Aster |
| Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack | Lobelia |
| Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 2 | Gladiolus |

---

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Very nice, clear, and complete answer, and great first contribution! Welcome to Arqade!

Answer (score 5):

One you enter the DLC, it stays at that level. The only ways to have it re-evaluate which level to be is to:

- Start a new character
- Reload a save file earlier to entering that DLC area
- Finish the main storyline, and enter the DLC *after* entering True Vault Hunter Mode (New Game +)

When you hit Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode (New Game ++), the DLC areas should scale to your level

Comment: "Finish the main storyline, and enter the DLC after entering True Vault Hunter Mode (New Game +)"  Which basically means you don't do the DLC on your first playthrough since, like everything else, the DLC resets for True and Ultimate Vault Hunter Modes.

Answer (score 3):

Both quests and DLC in Borderlands 2 have their level locked in each playthrough based on when you start them.  There's no real way of changing it in the current playthrough.

Note: There are two exceptions to this rule:

1. True Vault Hunter Mode: When you reach level 50, all content will automatically scale to level 50, which is the max level in True Vault Hunter Mode.
2. Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode: All content scales to your current level.

As an aside, although DLCs will scale to the level you start them at, they do have minimum and maximum levels in each playthrough:

- Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty has a range of 15-30 in Normal, 30-50 in TVHM.
- Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage has a range of 15-30 in Normal, 30-50 in TVHM.
- Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt has a range of 30-35 in Normal, 35-50 in TVHM.
- Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep has a range of 30-35 in Normal, 35-50 in TVHM.
- Headhunters 1-5 have a range of 15-35 in Normal, 32-50 in TVHM.

Answer (score 0):

The DLCs in Borderlands 2 do not scale to your level.

The solution is to level up some more before going back to it.